# How to overcome state Element Reference exception

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate the following actions:

1. Launching https://www.flipkart.com > Click on Mobiles > Mouse hover on Electronics and then click on Mi.

I am getting Expection in thread "main" state Element Reference: element is not attached to the page document in the miButton() method.

Please refer the error details section.

**HTML Code**

[Mi Button Click - HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gps49.jpg)

**Base class:**

```
public class Base {
    
        static WebDriver driver;
        
        
    public void setupBrowser(String browser, String url) {
        String currDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        
        if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", currDir + "\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
        else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", currDir + "\\drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }
        else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("edge")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", currDir + "\\drivers\\msedgedriver.exe");
            driver = new EdgeDriver();
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Valid browser not found therefore quitiing");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        
        if(url != "") 
            driver.get(url);
        else
            driver.get("about:blank");          
    }
    
    public void closeBrowser() {
        driver.close();
    }
```

**Page Class**

```
    public class pagetest extends Base{
    
        Actions action;
    
        public void closebtn() {
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button._2doB4z")).click();  
        }
    
        public void mibutton() {
            WebElement mobiles = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='Mobiles']"));  
    
            action = new Actions(driver);
            action.moveToElement(mobiles).click().perform();
    
    
            WebElement electronicsmenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Electronics']"));
            action.moveToElement(electronicsmenu).click().perform();
    
            List <WebElement> value = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='_1kidPb']/div[@class='_1QrT3s']//a");
            for(WebElement elem:value) {
                if(elem.getText().equals("Mi")) {
                    elem.click();
                }
            }
    
            WebElement label = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[text()='Latest from MI : ']"));
            System.out.println("The Label 'Latest from MI' is present : " +label.isEnabled());
        }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            pagetest obj = new pagetest();
            obj.setupBrowser("chrome", "https://www.flipkart.com/");
            obj.closebtn();
            obj.mibutton();
        }
    
    }
```

**Error Details**

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
(Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.90)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html

Comment: Please properly indent format your code as a code block. This is too difficult to read. We will also need a representative sample of the HTML code you are dealing with, plus the error message and stack trace. We also need to know which programming language you are using. Please add a tag to your question specific to your programming language.

Comment: First of all, avoid finding elements by text. On the page can be many elements with same text, but not each visible and/or clickable or even attached to the page document. Use explicit wait if StaleElementReferenceException persists.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I used explicit wait and a break at the end of if statement. It worked for me. Also, I will avoid finding elements by text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never find elements and then right away try to click on them. When the page is loading the elements are created, but after a few milliseconds they change their attributes, size and or location. This exception means that you found the element but as of now you "lost" it.

In order to avoid StateElementReferecneException use WebDriverWait object. You can wait for element to be visible / clickable as well as other options. Best option is to wait for the element to be clickable:

```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20, 10);        
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable
  (By.id("elementID")));
```